# Create pipes after fork

Tags: c, fork, pipe

Is it possible/correct to do this? If i do a write from fd1[1] of the "child" process, then make it possible to read from fd2[0] of the "father" process?

```
main(){
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid <0){
        return -1;
    }
    if(pid == 0){
        int fd1[2];
        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd1);
        pipe(fd2);
        close fd1[1];
        close fd2[0];
        //writes & reads between the fd1 pipes
        //writes & reads between the fd2 pipes
    }else{
        int fd1[2];
        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd1);
        pipe(fd2);
        close fd1[1];
        close fd2[0];
        //writes & reads between the fd1 pipes
        //writes & reads between the fd2 pipes
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? I doesn't look like something that you cannot test yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, pipes used to communicate between processes should be created *before* the `fork()` (otherwise, you have no easy way to send thru them, since the reading and the writing ends should be used by different processes).

<sup>there are dirty tricks to send a file descriptor between processes as an out of band message on socket, but I really forgot the details, which are ugly</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup the pipe **before forking**.

```
int fds[2];

if (pipe(fds))
    perror("pipe");

switch(fork()) {
case -1:
    perror("fork");
    break;
case 0:
    if (close(fds[0])) /* Close read. */
        perror("close");

    /* What you write(2) to fds[1] will end up in the parent in fds[0]. */

    break;
default:
    if (close(fds[1])) /* Close write. */
        perror("close");

    /* The parent can read from fds[0]. */

    break;
}
```